# EZAudio doesn't work with Bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, ezaudio

I am using `EZAudio` to playback streaming audio data. Here is the graph: `AUConverter -> MultiChannelMixer -> Output`. The `converter` is configured such that it converts audio data with a sampling rate of 48000 to device sampling rate (normally 44100). The audio data will be written into a `converter` node

```
AURenderCallbackStruct converterCallback;
    converterCallback.inputProc = EZOutputConverterInputCallback;
    converterCallback.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
    [EZAudioUtilities checkResult:AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(self.info->graph,
                                                              self.info->converterNodeInfo.node,
                                                              0,
                                                              &converterCallback)
                        operation:"Failed to set render callback on converter node"];
```

This graph works well with iphone's speakers. But when I select a bluetooth device, the callback is no longer triggered and no audio is played.
If I remove the `converter` node, I can play the audio again with a bluetooth device, but the sound quality is terrible. Please help, what am I missing in order to play audio in a bluetooth device.

Thanks.